# PUT request on existing Entity Framework objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity

I have 5 entity framework models and they all have relations with one another. Posting a new one to the database is simple, but trying to update them via a PUT request is getting really messy. I have to manually go into each collection and update what is being change.

```
        private void updateRelation(Dealer dealer)
    {
        var dealerOld = db.Dealers.Include(d => d.Contacts).Single(d => d.DealerID == dealer.DealerID);
        var contactsNew = dealer.Contacts;
        List<int> contactIds = new List<int>();

        if (dealer.DealerGroup == null ||
            dealerOld.DealerGroup == null ||
            dealer.DealerGroup.DealerGroupID != dealerOld.DealerGroup.DealerGroupID)
        {

            if (dealerOld.DealerGroup != null)
            {
                DealerGroup d = db.DealerGroups.Find(dealerOld.DealerGroupID);
                d.Dealers.Remove(dealerOld);
            }

        }

        updateManyToMany(dealer,dealerOld,contactIds,contactsNew);
    }

    private void updateManyToMany(Dealer dealer, Dealer dealerOld, List<int> contactIds, ICollection<Contact> contactsNew  )
    {

        foreach (var contact in contactsNew)
        {
            contactIds.Add(contact.ContactID);
        }

        foreach (var contact in dealerOld.Contacts.ToList())
        {
            if (!contactIds.Contains(contact.ContactID))
            {
                dealerOld.Contacts.Remove(contact);
            }
        }

        foreach (int contactId in contactIds)
        {
            if (!dealerOld.Contacts.Any(c => c.ContactID == contactId))
            {
                var contact = new Contact() { ContactID = contactId };
                dealerOld.Contacts.Add(contact);
                db.Contacts.Attach(contact);
            }
        }
    }
```

is there a simpler way of doing this

Answer (score 0):

- https://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/864

There are many other questions related to this, you may want to spend a little bit of time sifting through the answers for workarounds in the meantime, or wait for a more helpful answer.